# Using log4j DailyRollingFileAppender to not roll at midnight but at another time such as 4PM

Tags: java, log4j

is there a way I can use log4j DailyRollingFileAppender to create a new file at another time other than midnight, such as 4 PM. So instead of rolling at 12:00 PM it will roll at 4:PM. Changing the timezone in which the machine is running is not a valid option, at least for my application

Comment: Have a look at `CronTriggeringPolicy` here : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Comment: @Berger: OP asked about log4j (1), not log4j2.